# After installed the new MAMP version, i cannot access WP-ADMIN

Tags: wordpress, mamp, updates

i've just installed the new MAMP update and suddenly i cannot log in to my wp-admin.

the website is working fine on my machine but i cannot edit it.

whenever i'm typing: *...localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-admin/*

it's just go white.

is there any solution?

thanks a lot!

Tomer

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at the error log... Usually, there is a plugin or theme issue. Perhaps a stray character or a missing ';'. If there is not error log file, simply remove delete all plugins and see if the problem is resolved. Then, you can add them one by one again to see which one breaks the page...